# Как я могу спарсить YouTube?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Я пробовал два способа получения html-кода страницы - с помощью requests и с помощью selenium, но у каждого есть критичная для меня проблема: в случае с requests он возвращает неверный код (как я понял, это происходит потому, что он возвращает код до запуска java-составляющей), в случае с selenium две проблемы: первая - он странно медленно работает. Запуская код на своем компьютере, у меня висит открытая вкладка хрома секунд 20, после чего я получаю html-код. И вторая проблема selenium`а - я подозреваю, что это не сработает на хостинге. Как мне решить данную проблему?

Comment: Если хотите работать в "разрешенной" зоне YouTube, то "копайте" в сторону youtube api, ну а если хотите "вскрыть", то вам сюда https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/tree/master, как раз на питоне написано :)  Библиотека обновляется, и при изменении кода YouTube Ваша программа не перестанет работать.